# React add table cell flash animation on useState change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am buildin a dynamic table using React.

The application consumes data from a websocket and every time there is a new message coming I update the state that contains the data table. I want to add a blinking flash just to the cell that contains the data that changed, but since the whole state is updating the whole table re renders obviously.

My component:

```
  const [contracts, setContracts] = useState([]);
  const [isContracts, setIsContracts] = useState(false);
  const [isSocket, setIsSocket] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchContracts = async () => {
      try {
        // ..PULLING DATA FROM THE SERVER
        // 
        setContracts((prevContracts) => [...prevContracts, ...grouped]);

        setIsContracts(true);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };

    // Avoid multiple XHR connections
    if (!isContracts) {
      fetchContracts();
    }
  }, [setContracts]);


  const updateQuote = (data) => {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(data);
    if (parsed.type === 'book_top') {
      const { contract_id, ask, bid } = parsed;

      const newContracts = contracts.map((x) => {
        if (x.put && x.call) {
          if (x.put.id === contract_id) {
            x.put.ask = ask;
            x.put.bid = bid;
          } else if (x.call.id === contract_id) {
            x.call.ask = ask;
            x.call.bid = bid;
          }
        }
        return x;
      });


     // THIS IS WHERE RELEVANTE STATE UPDATE HAPPENS
      setContracts(newContracts);
    }
  };


// this is where the data is being pulled from WS 
if (!isSocket) {
      socket = io('http://localhost:4000');
      setIsSocket(true);
      socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('connected to socket');
      });
      socket.on('quotes', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        updateQuote(data);
      });
    }

return (
    <div>
      {contracts && (
        <ResponsiveTable data={contracts} />
      )}
    </div>
```

My table code:

```
const ResponsiveTable = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div className='table-wrapper'>
      <table className='fl-table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className={'blue-bg'}>OI</th>
            <th className={'blue-bg'}>Bid</th>
            <th className={'blue-bg'}>Ask</th>
            <th className={'purple-bg'}>Strike</th>
            <th className={'green-bg'}>Bid</th>
            <th className={'green-bg'}>Ask</th>
            <th className={'green-bg'}>OI</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((option) => {
            if (item && item.put) {
              const { call, data_expires, put, strike_price } = item;
              return (
                <tr key={uuidv4()}>
                  <td>{call.open_interest}</td>
                  <td>{call.bid}</td>
                  <td>{call.ask}</td>
                  <td>{strike_price}</td>
                  <td>{put.bid}</td>
                  <td>{put.ask}</td>
                  <td>{put.open_interest}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            }
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My blink animation (This should be triggered just in the cell where the text is updated)

```
td {
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  animation: blinker 1s linear 2 !important;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

I am not sure what the best solution to this is. Ideally a CSS class should be added to the td item that contains the element with new content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you using key wrongly:

```
return (
        <tr key={uuidv4()}>
           <td>{call.open_interest}</td>
```

This way everytime component is re-rendered, a new key will be generated so React will always create new tr element instead of updating the current tr element. That's way your entire table are re-rendered completely.
One solution is using id from the data:

```
return (
            <tr key={item.id}>
               <td>{call.open_interest}</td>
```

Comment: thanks just fixed that. How would you do the blinking thing?

Comment: @greatTeacherOnizuka: you can create new prop for ResponsiveTable to let it knows which cell need to do the blinking:
        <ResponsiveTable data={contracts} blinkingCell={celid}/>
And in the ResponsiveTable we can conditional apply the blinking class for the updated cell
 <td  className={props.blinkingCell === `${item.id}_open_interest` ? "blinking" : ""}>{call.open_interest}</td>